# Upgrade Helm Error: the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have successfully installed my helm chart and was trying to change the value of my image version by doing:

```
helm upgrade --set myAppVersion=1.0.7 myApp . --atomic --reuse-values
```

This upgrade fails with this error:

The command fails with this error:

> Error: UPGRADE FAILED: an error occurred while rolling back the
> release. original upgrade error: cannot patch "myappsecret" with
> kind Secret: Operation cannot be fulfilled on secrets
> "myappsecret": the object has been modified; please apply your
> changes to the latest version and try again: cannot patch
> "myappsecret" with kind Secret: Operation cannot be fulfilled on
> secrets "diffgramsecret": the object has been modified; please apply
> your changes to the latest version and try again

It's somehow related to a secret I have in my deployment:

This its the yaml file of the secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: {{ .Values.imagePullCredentials.gcrCredentials }}
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-01-20T22:54:29Z"
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:data:
        .: {}
        f:.dockerconfigjson: {}
      f:type: {}
    manager: kubectl
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-01-20T22:54:29Z"
  name: myappsecret
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "2073"
  uid: 7c99cb08-5576-4fa3-b6f9-d8d11d76d32c
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

This secret is used on my deployments to fetch the docker image from our GCR docker registry.

I'm not sure why this is causing problems, because the only value I'm changing is the docker image tag.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Most of that `metadata:` is automatically generated; Kubernetes will update the `resourceVersion:` and `time:` on its own when the file is loaded into the cluster.  Is this actually in your Helm template file; can you delete all of it besides the `name:`?

Comment: Yes this was an autogenerated secret. Thanks for that insight, I will try deleting everything except the name: key.